# Custom PyPI repo for Google Dataflow workers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I want to use a custom pypi repo for my Dataflow workers. Typically, to configure a custom pypi repo, you would edit `/etc/pip.conf` to look like this:

```
[global]
index-url = https://pypi.customer.com/
```

Since I can't run a startup script for Dataflow workers, my thought was to perform this operation at the head of my `setup.py` file, so that as the script executes, it would update `/etc/pip.conf` before attempting a pip install of the dependencies.

My `setup.py` looks like the following:

```
with open('/etc/pip.conf', 'w') as pip_conf:
  pip_conf.write("""
  [global]
  index-url = https://artifactory.mayo.edu/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-remote/simple
  """)

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'custom_package',
]

setuptools.setup(
    name='wordcount',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='demo package.',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages())
```

The odd thing is that my workers are **hanging** indefinitely. When I ssh into them, I see some Docker containers running, but I am not sure how to debug further.

Any suggestions on how I can hack the Dataflow workers to use a custom pypi url?

Comment: have you looked at the worker-startup logs in stackdriver?

Comment: If the issue still occurs, can you share the suspicious records from worker-startup logs?

Comment: Thanks for the help - one log to note is:  `"Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/flask/` 
Which leads me to believe that pip was configured to use a custom repo, and therefore my `setup.py` did not _execute_ on the worker nodes.
Does `setup.py` get executed by the workers themselves?  Or is it used ahead of time to pre-build the Python package?

Comment: Have you tried to alter `pip.conf` in `setup.py` with [CUSTOM_COMMANDS](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b8c001c6f4367b6b96d9af330b67f865cccecabf/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset/setup.py#L78)?

Comment: Like adding something like this: `"echo", "-e", "[global]\nindex-url = https://pypi.customer.com/", ">", "/etc/pip.conf"`

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a good candidate for [custom containers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/environments/), where you can install everything exactly as you want rather than having to hack the worker startup sequence.

Comment: Interesting - can you tell me more about custom containers?  I'm not aware of any way to specify the runtime for Dataflow workers.